# facebook audience-network-sdk -> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError onAdEventManagerCreated when updating to recent versions

Tags: android, facebook-ads-api, nosuchmethoderror, facebook-audience-network

I'm using 6.5.1 with no problems:

```
implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:6.5.1'

            bannerListener = new AdListener() {
                @Override public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {}
                @Override public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {}
                @Override public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {}
                @Override public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {}
            };
            loading = true;
            banner = new AdView(context, id, AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);
            banner.loadAd(banner.buildLoadAdConfig().withAdListener(bannerListener).build());
```

But if I update the sdk to `6.11.0` or even `6.6.0`, i'm getting this exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method onAdEventManagerCreated(Landroid/content/Context;)V in class Lcom/facebook/ads/internal/api/InitApi; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.facebook.ads.internal.api.InitApi' appears in /data/data/com.myapp.core/code_cache/.overlay/base.apk/classes.dex)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.U4.A04(:55533)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.U4.<init>(:55521)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.U4.A01(:55528)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.X3.A5Z(:65854)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.8J.A08(:18206)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.cS.<init>(:71757)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.F8.<init>(:32983)
    at com.facebook.ads.redexgen.X.4x.<init>(:12836)
    at com.facebook.ads.internal.dynamicloading.DynamicLoaderImpl.createAdViewApi(:133)
    at com.facebook.ads.AdView.<init>(AdView.java:102)
    at com.myapp.ad.facebook.FacebookAdEntity.init(FacebookAdEntity.java:86)
```

The error line is `banner = new AdView(context, id, AdSize.BANNER_HEIGHT_50);`

Does anyone have any idea about what is happening?

I'm building with api 31:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I simply deleted Android Studio cache and restarted it... now it works...

Seems that some bug on it was producing the issue. Don't sure what, but a restart with cache cleaning solved it.